# Prove an extension is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

K is a field and $char(K)=p$, $K(s,t)$ is the field of rational functions in variable $s$ and $t$. Now $K(s^{p},t^{p})\subseteq K(s,t)$. Prove that $K(s,t)$ is a simple field extension of $K(s^{p},t^{p})$ ( which means $K(s,t)=K(s^{p},t^{p})(u)$ ).

Right now I can prove that the degree of this extension is $p^{2}$ and I want to prove by contradiction. But I don't know how to derive a contradiction.

Comment: This seems very close to you are asking: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276627/a-finite-field-extension-that-is-not-simple

Comment: I think you want to prove that the extension *is not simple*.

Comment: On the contrary, it can be shown that this extension is not simple, and this is the most classical example of non simple extension.