# Finite extension that is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question is from Kaplansky *Fields and Rings* 1.9.2

> **2.** Let $K$ have characteristic $p$ and $L = K(u,v)$ where $u^p$, $v^p\in K$ and $[L:K] = p^2$. Show that $L$ is not a simple extension of $K$ and exhibit an infinite number of intermediate fields.

I am confused since the field $K$ could be finite. if $K$ is finite, then there are finitely many intermediate fields. 
I searched the internet, all related questions said the field $K$ and $L$ are function fields.

related questions :
[Intermediate fields of a finite field extension that is not separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823100/intermediate-fields-of-a-finite-field-extension-that-is-not-separable)

[A finite field extension that is not simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276627/a-finite-field-extension-that-is-not-simple)

Answer (score 4):

The assumptions of the problem imply $K$ is not finite.  Indeed, $x\mapsto x^p$ is a bijection from any finite field of characteristic $p$ to itself, so if $K$ were finite then $u^p,v^p\in K$ would imply $u,v\in K$ so $[L:K]$ would be $1$, not $p^2$.